# Sinatra: Avoiding code on the template

Tags: ruby, sinatra, crud, dry

I am new to Ruby and Sinatra but I've read a bit about Rails. One of the things Rails masters tell us to do is to leave code out of the templates.

Well, here is my code, right where the information is needed in my template. It works but, for the sake of learning the best practices, how could I move this out of my template into my app.rb file without repeating it in every block of code (CRUD) which relies on the template?

```
<h2>Status</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Received<span><%= Inbox.count %></span></li>
  <li>Sent<span><%= Outbox.all(:processed => 1).count %></span></li>
  <li><Scheduled<span><%= Outbox.all(:error => -1).count %></span></li>
  <li>Error<span><%= Outbox.all(:error.not => [-1,0]).count %></span></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: In general you want your views calling variables from Helpers or Controllers so instead of `Inbox.count` you might have something like `@inbox_count` in the controller powering the view.

Comment: Also, these questions are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, @ScottJShea . I wasn't even aware there was such forum [codereview.stackexchange.com]. I will keep that in mind for future posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to @Beat Richartz's answer - not because it's wrong but because there are lots of alternatives…

#### 1. Helpers

[Helpers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers) are available in templates. e.g.

```
helpers do
  def mailbox_stats
    @mailbox_stats ||= {
      :inbox_count     => Inbox.count
      :sent_count      => Outbox.all(:processed => 1).count
      :scheduled_count => Outbox.all(:error => -1).count
      :errored_count   => Outbox.all(:error.not => [-1,0])
    }
  end
end
```

and in the template:

```
<h2>Status</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Received<span><%= mailbox_stats[:inbox_count] %></span></li>
  <li>Sent<span><%= mailbox_stats[:sent_count]  %></span></li>
  <li><Scheduled<span><%= mailbox_stats[:scheduled_count] %></span></li>
  <li>Error<span><%= mailbox_stats[:errored_count] %></span></li>
</ul>
```

#### 2. Settings

[Settings](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuration) probably aren't the best idea for this situation, but it can be done, maybe if you wanted to set some defaults:

```
config do
  set :mailbox_stats, {
      :inbox_count     => 0
      :sent_count      => 0
      :scheduled_count => 0
      :errored_count   => 0
    }
end

before do
  if @user.has? :inbox # or something relevant
    settings.mailbox_stats.replace( {
      :inbox_count     => Inbox.count
      :sent_count      => Outbox.all(:processed => 1).count
      :scheduled_count => Outbox.all(:error => -1).count
      :errored_count   => Outbox.all(:error.not => [-1,0])
    })
 end
end

<h2>Status</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Received<span><%= settings.mailbox_stats[:inbox_count] %></span></li>
  <li>Sent<span><%= settings.mailbox_stats[:sent_count]  %></span></li>
  <li><Scheduled<span><%= settings.mailbox_stats[:scheduled_count] %></span></li>
  <li>Error<span><%= settings.mailbox_stats[:errored_count] %></span></li>
</ul>
```

#### 3. Local variables

[Like limiting your scope?](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20Variables%20in%20Templates)

```
get('/or_so') do
  erb :your_template, :locals => { :mailbox_stats => {
          :inbox_count     => Inbox.count
          :sent_count      => Outbox.all(:processed => 1).count
          :scheduled_count => Outbox.all(:error => -1).count
          :errored_count   => Outbox.all(:error.not => [-1,0])
    }
  }
end
```

in the template:

```
<h2>Status</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Received<span><%= mailbox_stats[:inbox_count] %></span></li>
  <li>Sent<span><%= mailbox_stats[:sent_count]  %></span></li>
  <li><Scheduled<span><%= mailbox_stats[:scheduled_count] %></span></li>
  <li>Error<span><%= mailbox_stats[:errored_count] %></span></li>
</ul>
```

I'd probably use a helper.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, Iain. I had read the 'Helpers' portion of the documentation but it was so brief and elusive I could not really graps how to use it in my case. I think I will stick to that (love the hash usage) though @Beat Richartz's answer shows what I originally thought would be the way to go. Big thanks to you guys.

Comment: Just a question: Does "mailbox_stats" get updated just once or every time the template is displayed? Ideally, numbers should be always 'fresh' so the templates display the updated figures.

Comment: @Daniel [A new instance of the app is instantiated with every new request](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Request/Instance%20Scope), so the numbers should be fresh. However, in the helper you can see I've cached the result for subsequent calls, so calling the helper repeatedly within the same request would only use the figures it first grabbed (until a new request…). You could change that, it was just an example, it depends what you need. I reckon it would be ok as it is.

Comment: I was about to delete my question, having tested it myself. Fantastic! Thanks a bunch. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just load the counts into instance variables where you define the routes:

```
get('/or_so') do
  @inbox_count     = Inbox.count
  @sent_count      = Outbox.all(:processed => 1).count
  @scheduled_count = Outbox.all(:error => -1).count
  @errored_count   = Outbox.all(:error.not => [-1,0])

  erb :your_template
end
```

If you're going to load these over multiple pages, there's also `before`

```
before(/this|insane|regexp|to|grep|locations/) do
  # assign variables
end
```

Comment: Much appreciated, BeatRichartz. I knew there must be a way. I used variables inside the routes but it just seemed like repeating code (not DRY). I will try 'before - do'. I had selected your answer as 'best answer' but @iain's expands on yours, making it more complete for beginners like myself.